# Variation on how to combine values from multiple rows into a single row in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Hi I am trying to adapt the excellent VBA that was posted previously to go through data and take all lines with the same id in column 1 and add them all into one row for each.
Trying to get from this:

[image: Start point]

To this

[image: End point]

but the adapted code below only ever combines 2 rows even if there are more than two with the same id in column 1.

```
Sub CombineInvoices()
Dim currentRow As Long
Dim currentCol As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 
currentCol = 4
For currentRow = LastRow To 2 Step -1
    If Cells(currentRow, 1) = Cells(currentRow - 1, 1) Then
        Range(Cells(currentRow, 1), Cells(currentRow, 4)).Copy Destination:=Range(Cells(currentRow - 1, currentCol + 1), Cells(currentRow - 1, currentCol + 4))
        Rows(currentRow).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next
currentCol = currentCol + 4
End Sub
```

All help really gratefully received.

[if you move the currentCol = currentCol + 4 statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tz6ED.png)

Comment: `currentCol = currentCol + 4` is at the wrong place, you need to place it just above `End IF`

Comment: Thanks Mate. Still only combines two of the rows but adds a 12 cell space between the two entrys for invoice number 12345. Added picture of result above

Comment: This question refers to “… the excellent VBA that was posted previously”. I guess that refers to [How to combine values from multiple rows into a single row in Excel?](//superuser.com/q/395126/150988), based on the similarity in titles (and vague similarity in content).

Answer (score 0):

Managed to work it out. I was deleting the rows as I was going separated the copy and delete statements as below and all is working! Yay!

```
Sub CombineRowsRevisitedStep()
Dim currentRow As Long
Dim currentCol As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
currentCol = 4
For currentRow = LastRow To 2 Step -1
    If Cells(currentRow, 1) = Cells(currentRow - 1, 1) Then
        Range(Cells(currentRow, 1), Cells(currentRow, currentCol)).Copy Destination:=Range(Cells(currentRow - 1, 4), Cells(currentRow - 1, currentCol + 30))
    currentCol = currentCol + 4
    End If
Next
For currentRow = LastRow To 2 Step -1
    If Cells(currentRow, 1) = Cells(currentRow - 1, 1) Then
        Rows(currentRow).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next
End Sub
```